# Has anyone gotten TypeScript debugging in Visual Studio working?

Tags: debugging, typescript

I'm writing a Windows 8.1 HTML5/Javascript store app and posts about this refer to using source map files in a supported browser. Just curious if anyone has gotten this working seamlessly by placing a breakpoint in their .ts file in Visual Studio.

Comment: The lasts posts I can find about this are about a year old so I'm hoping something has changed here...

Comment: Yes, I have gotten it to work somewhat consistently. If it isn't working, I'd suggest just trying a `debugger;` command to get things to stop where you want.

Comment: Can WiredPrairie and NatiKrisi tell something about HOW they got it working?

Answer (score 1):

## Windows 8.1 project

If you are facing issues with debugging TypeScript in Win8.1, I'd suggest to download and run sample/working project first. E.g. [Encyclopaedia](http://typescript.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#samples/win8/encyclopedia/Encyclopedia/) works for me, see:

[image]

**The trick** is in [JavaScript mapping files](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/). So, if this works for you, copy important parts from [Encyclopedia.jsproj](http://typescript.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#samples/win8/encyclopedia/Encyclopedia/Encyclopedia.jsproj) (like TypeScriptSourceMap at the very end of file and Import of TypeScript .targets) to your jsproj. Hope this helps.

## Web project

To debug JavaScript or TypeScript run your application using an Internet Explorer:

1. In Standard toolbar change a Debug target to IE

   [image: change a Debug target to IE]
2. Navigate to your .ts file and place the breakpoint
3. Press the green arrow :o)

If it still doesn't work, install the [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) extension.

I have it tested also with Chrome and FF, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This question was not for a web application. It is specifically for a Windows 8 WinJS native application using TypeScript.